# parse html content by passing custom date input

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I am parsing data from [here](https://markets.ft.com/data/world/economic-calendar?mhq5j=e2). On the webpage I can get data for example yesterday by selecting the desired date. How can I parse to get the same data (ie. yesterday)? Like, pass custom dates to get data for that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `Selenium` or use the site's ajax api.
Here is an example of the latter:

```
def get_by_date(date):
    url = 'https://markets.ft.com/data/world/ajax/getnextecoevents?startDate=' + date
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()['html']
```

`date` should be formatted as yyyy-mm-dd, eg: "2017-07-20"

Using the above function and `bs4` to scrape the table contents:

```
html = get_by_date('2017-06-20')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = [[td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in soup.find('table').find_all('tr')]
```

Comment: thanks it seems to parse by desired date. But how do i get the text content from here on. Usually, I work with xpath, but in this case, it does not seem to get to the text

Comment: Why don't you use `bs4` ? If you tell me which columns you're trying to scrape, maybe i could help.

Comment: I am trying to scrape contents the main table [date, description, country, impact, prior, 4cast, actual]

Comment: I updated my post to give you an example with `bs4`.