# parse text from html source code

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

in continuation with this: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226861/parse-html-content-by-passing-custom-date-input)
i have a html source code [here](https://markets.ft.com/data/world/ajax/getnextecoevents?startDate=2017-07-15). How can i parse the text data from this html source code. I usually work with `lxml.xpath` to parse text data from html tables. But in this case i am not able to get the desired text with `xpath` The code i am trying is

```
lxml.html.fromstring(requests.get(url).content).xpath("//tr//td//text()")
```

Comment: The URL you point to the the question does not seem to load pure HTML. It looks like JSON with the HTML embedded in a field. The URL implies AJAX so I'm guessing it is a SOAP call. Try using the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module on the content then [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) on the HTML field.